# IE11 Ignoring Inline CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

Site being developed here: http://new.brushman.com/about/

The CMS allows adding of in-line CSS on a page by page basis.  This CSS is added to the page after all other .css files are loaded.

IE11 is ignoring the style, even-though it works in 8, 9, 10, Edge, and all the rest (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc)

The inline CSS is:

```
<style>
/* CMS Page about CSS */
main {background: #d70055;}
</style>
```

and is in the  *after* all the css files are loaded

The interesting thing is that inspect element shows the background with a checkmark, and it's at the top of the list indicating it has the highest priority.

There are no opaque elements covering the element.

Some things I've tried:
!important
removing the comments
adding additional new lines
using rgba

Completely and thoroughly stumped.

Comment: What about using background-color?

Comment: Hm... did you tried with #main? (id css selector)

Comment: @nevermind  No. I am loading respond.js, so maybe that explains why 8,9 and 10 work.  I suppose Edge on Win10 works because it's a proper browser...

Comment: Another reason to avoid styling via element names vs classes.

Comment: @ScottSimpson  Correct me if I am incorrect, but if my css was <main class="foo"> and my css was main.foo{background:#fff;} it still wouldn't work because main still isn't a block element?  What's inherently bad about styling element names if no classes are needed?  Seems more efficient and less code...

Comment: Hey @CraigJacobs -- yes your are correct. However, if you only set styles via class names it makes them a bit more reusable, and easier to remember.
It may not be as applicable in the case of the 'main' element as in the case of a span or div.

Comment: Agreed. As a rule I don't style span, div, paragraph, etc unless it's "class class div" or "div.class".  applying classes to to just div or span would be problematic in most cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
main {
    display: block;
    background: #d70055;
}
```

IE does not treat unknown types of elements as block elements - just like [the <main> element](http://roger.steneteg.org/blog/html5-main-element-tag-not-working-in-ie11) in this case.

Comment: Correct; you need `display:block`, because IE does not have this in its browser default style sheet like the other browsers do.

Comment: Huh.  That works.  Any idea why 8,9,10 work without that?  I am loading respond.js using the html comment method, maybe that has something to do with it?  Doesn't really matter as long as it works, but it is curious...

Comment: @CraigJacobs It's actually your `modernizer.custom.26434.min.js` file that is correcting this in earlier versions of IE. It provides a level of recognition for common HTML5 elements that most modern browsers already have. It simply isn't identifying IE11 as needing to have this compensation executed. I'm afraid that none of these "modernization" JavaScripts compensate for all the HTML5 element quirks. They change with every new browser subversion. It's significantly less work to build them for older versions and update it when a new version is released.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley IE11 does not support the new `<main>` html semantic element.

Comment: This is the correct answer, source: http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic could the downvoter please explain his action?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer because you are technically correct. However, IE11 is still capable of rendering non-standard elements with user-defined CSS. Any elements that are not recognized by IE11 will render with `display: inline;`. Custom elements in IE has always been allowed, it's a matter of compensating for the default CSS applied to those elements.

Comment: I up-voted your comment, because it is true, but I accepted @Keammoort answer because it solved the issue.  The main element was there and rendering - it just wasn't styling correctly because the browser wasn't treating it as a block level element.  main{display:block} fixed the issue.